Sqlite slower response with String criteria
I have a table with three columns. Two are BIGINT  data type columns and one is varchar(512) data type.
Using java language.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `UNIQUE_ENTITIES` (DETAILS_ID BIGINT, ACCOUNT_ID BIGINT, ENTITY varchar(512));

#After inserting the data creating indexes

create INDEX `idx1` on `UNIQUE_ENTITIES` (ACCOUNT_ID);
create INDEX `idx2` on `UNIQUE_ENTITIES` (ENTITY);


Have index on two columns ACCOUNT_ID, ENTITY.
Here is my select query::
select DETAILS_ID from `UNIQUE_ENTITIES` where ACCOUNT_ID=112323 and ENTITY='21f442-678f97-fgh382-47d828';


This query takes nearly 150 ms in 312GB NVme disk and 32 GB RAM machine.
Total rows count is 1.5 million
QUERY PLAN: SEARCH UNIQUE_ENTITIES USING INDEX idx1 (ACCOUNT_ID=?)
If I run a query with ACCOUNT_ID only in criteria it returns results in 2 ms.
select DETAILS_ID from `UNIQUE_ENTITIES` where ACCOUNT_ID=112323;


QUERY PLAN: SEARCH UNIQUE_ENTITIES USING INDEX idx1 (ACCOUNT_ID=?)
What should I do here to improve performance, Any suggestions are welcome to improve this.

How long does executing a query with only where ENTITY='21f442-678f97-fgh382-47d828' take?

"it returns results in 2 ms".  Are you sure about that?  Or does it start returning results in 2 ms?  How many seconds elapse until you have received all results?

What gives EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN for both requests? Before trying to guess it is often more efficient to directly ask SQLite how it decide to handle a request...

@Dogbert it took150 ms

@MikeNakis yes, I queried this via java, the query result time difference is 2 ms

@SergeBallesta As i used Java i didn't tried EXPLAIN will try this out

I've seen this happen before where SQLite chooses a non-optimal column to filter first. We would need the query plan for all 3 queries to confirm like Serge suggested.

https://sqlite.org/queryplanner.html is an introduction to how sqlite uses indexes that is essential reading.

Edited the question with Query Plan.
QUERY PLAN: SEARCH UNIQUE_ENTITIES USING INDEX idx1 (ACCOUNT_ID=?)
@SergeBallesta

@MikeNakis query plan added in the question

The query plan is the same for both queries. That means that the first phase is the same. If the index is not selective enough (i.e. you have a lot of rows for ACCOUNT_ID=112323), the query for only ACCOUNT_ID returns immediately after reading the index while the one with two clauses has to read all the rows. But if you execute the queries and fetch all the rows, the one with both ACCOUNT_ID and ENTITY should be faster because if it returns less rows.

You need a compound index to cover the WHERE clause:
WHERE ACCOUNT_ID = 112323 AND ENTITY = '21f442-678f97-fgh382-47d828';

For example:
CREATE INDEX idx3 ON UNIQUE_ENTITIES (ACCOUNT_ID, ENTITY);


will try this, will this make a difference?

My prediction is that it will make a difference.  I am not sure whether it will make enough difference.  Let's see.  (-:=

Query plan for the above one : SEARCH UNIQUE_ENTITIES USING INDEX indx67 (ACCOUNT_ID=? AND ENTITY =?)
When I use this there is no difference some times query time got increases.
@MikeNakis

@DAK next up, try adding an index with those two columns in the opposite order, run ANALYZE, and see which of the two gets selected. (Then drop the other one)

I think the problem is that you don't understand how indexing works: You made some indices and you assume they will speed things up sufficiently.
Indices indeed speed things up, but only if they actually end up being used.
How do you know? EXPLAIN
To know if they are used, you can use the EXPLAIN SQL command: Just stick that in front of your query and run it (so, it now looks like EXPLAIN SELECT ...) - and you SQL engine will explain how it is going to tackle your query. Understanding EXPLAIN output is a bit of a skill in itself, and EXPLAIN generally does not explain (heh) why it chose that path, but, here you should be able to figure out that it only uses one of those 2 indices; the other one isn't used at all. That doesn't explain why the other index isn't used, but it does explain why this query would be relatively slow.
What is an index?
I'm oversimplifying here; there are many kinds of index which I'm going to elide over, for example. Just the basics so you know what they are, how much they cost, how they speed up queries, or more to the point here: When they will not help in the slightest.
Imagine you have a complex phone book that maps any inhabitant of a village not just to their phone number, but to their name, current occupation, address, phone number, favourite colour, and list of hobbies.
Phone books are generally sorted on name; we can do that here but that immediately poses a bit of an issue when folks move about: When somebody moves into this village, you have to find the page where their last name 'fits', and then insert them. This is going to take a ton of time: All pages in the book from the page that lists their name now have to be reprinted because everything moves down by one (this simile works for computer systems too: If you store data this way, you need to rewrite all bytes from the insertion point onwards, you can't ask a disk to insert new bytes in the middle!)
It would have been so much more convenient if we could just write their name at the end - that means we only need to reprint the last page of everybody's phonebook.
Separately, it would have been nice if we could look stuff up, say, based on favourite color. But we can't.
Enter: Indices.
An index is like a mini phonebook. We rework our phonebook to be unsorted, which gives us the great advantage that we can just stick new inhabitants on the final page; they can go anywhere, and that's as good a place as any. Also, each entry gets its position listed (So, the first entry starts with '1', the second with '2', etcetera). To maintain the ability to quickly look up an inhabitant based on name, we now make a tiny little 'companion phonebook'. This phonebook lists, per name, only the 'position in the actual phonebook'. So, it just lists "D. AK - 12951".
If I want to find your favourite colour, my procedure is now:

Look up D. AK in the companion minibook. This gets me 12951.
Look up 12951 in the big book. This gets me everything about you including your favourite color.

This solves a lot of problems! If a new inhabitant moves in, we have to reprint most of our mini phonebook which is annoying, but at least we're just reprinting a tiny book now. We can also solve the problem of "I want to sort on favourite color": We simply make a second companion phonebook that just maps favourite colour to a position. This is an example of a non-unique sorting element, so any given favourite colour lists multiple positions.
Those mini books are what indices are!
And again this mental model maps very well to reality: Index are far more expensive than you think they are - they are copies of a table, but, permanently sorted (which is quite expensive when inserting and deleting!), although most columns are stripped out (for example, in the 'favourite colour' book, all columns are gone other than favourite colour and position). (SQL Engines do optimize a bit and will simply mark a row as 'deleted' so any operations that see it know to just skip it, and have a smallish list of 'oh and there were added later' than any operations take into account, so that the engine can start the work on rewriting that mini-phonebook when its not so busy and whilst its doing that, the old version with the 'very recently added list' can be used until it is done).
Why your query is slow
So, translating your setup: You have the big phonebook with all the details, and 2 mini-book: One that maps account id to position, and a second one that maps entity name to position. Neither minibook is unique: Any given account ID maps to multiple positions, and any given entity name also maps to multiple positions.
I now give you an account ID and an entity name and I expect you find me the one person in town that is unique described by that combination as fast as you can.
You cannot do this job.
You can look up a whole bevy of positions in one book (say, 500), then look up a whole bevy of positions in the other (say, 250), and now you need to take the set of 500 positions + the set of 250 positions and find the one position number that is in both of them.
Alternatively, you take the more specific index (here, the 250), and just check each of the 250 entries in the big book to check if the account ID matches up.
Both operations are certainly a lot faster than going through the big book page by page (which is what happens if you SELECT when no indices exist/can be used at all).. but still orders of magnitude slower than a simple unique index lookup.
What you really need is yet another phonebook: This phonebook is contains 3 columns: Account ID, Entity, and Position. It's primarily sorted on Account ID, and secondarily on Entity: For all lines in this book with account ID 1951, that subset is itself sorted on Entity.
When you have this third book, you can do my task extremely fast: You look up the account ID with binary search. That's very fast: You open the phone book to the middle page, check if the account ID is higher or lower than the one you want, which lets you rip off and toss out half of the minibook safe in the knowledge that the answer can't be in that, and then you - apply that again. You continue to toss out half of whatever is left until only one entry is left, which goes very fast (for example, if your phone book contains 4 billion entries, it still takes only 32 "toss half out" to get to a single result; 2*2*2*.....*2 = 2^32 = 4.294.967.296 after all).
Then you look up the first line that has a higher account ID, and you have now 'squeezed' the result into this relatively small set of lines. You then do a binary search through these lines too - because they are sorted on Entity and you know which Entity so the same algorithm works here just as well.
So, do that; ask the DB engine to make and maintain this minibook:
CREATE INDEX idx3 ON UNIQUE_ENTITIES (ACCOUNT_ID, ENTITY);

Careful!
Think about your phonebook that maps account ID to positions, then about this new book that maps account_ID+entity to positions.
You never need the first phonebook. It's pointless. The new book can do the job just as well. So, ditch that index, it just costs time for the DB engine to maintain it for no real gain.
However, the second book (the one on entity) is still useful! Given the new book, you can't use it to meaningfully speed up the query of 'give me the names of everybody that works for entity XYZ).
It now seems, perhaps, that you should never make simple (single column) indices: After all, adding another column is 'free' - the index is just as good when you just care about the first column. But, not so fast: Taken to its logical extreme you shove every column in your index and now your index is a literal exact copy of your main table, except, it needs to be maintained in a very specific sorting order which is quite expensive.
There's, unfortunately, no shortcuts here. You must only make those indices you actually need, and you must make them specifically to cover the precise query form.
Note that this idea goes as far as you want to take it. For example, most DB engines will have absolutely no problem with creating an index on a function. Consider an index on name of folks in town. You then do a search with WHERE LOWER(phonebook.fullName) = LOWER("NameIWantToLookUp"). The index will not be used because that LOWER throws a wrench in the works 1.
But, you can make an index ON LOWER(phonebook.fullName) no problem, and that index certainly would be used!

[1] Various DB engines actually would use that index because they do some smart stuff on indices on VARCHAR columns; approaches differ. Some apply the concept of a collation order (basically, a mapping function that is always applied when indicing) and use a case insensitive one for example.
[2] The indices described in this answer are tree based; that, too, isn't necessary. They can be hash based for example. But the general principle doesn't change: Indices are copies of the main table, stripped, and maintained in some well defined order.

Was ChatGPT or some other LLM involved here?

@TimBiegeleisen Nope.

@TimBiegeleisen come on, LLMs don't write like that.  Luckily, we can still tell.
